# CSS textbox size in SP Designer 2007

Tags: css

The following is used in SP designer to render the following Label and Textbox in sharepoint 2007 designer.

```
<table width="100%" style="border: thin solid silver">
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        Current  Hours*
                    </td>

                    <td >
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff18{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Contracted_x0020_Hours" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff18',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Contracted_x0020_Hours')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff18description{$Pos}" FieldName="Contracted_x0020_Hours" ControlMode="New"/>

                    </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

How do I change the size of texbox.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify the css style using there and changed it accordingly... or if you use jQuery try:

```
$("input[id^='ff18']").css('height',20);
$("input[id^='ff18']").css('width',50);
```

for example...